# How do I move thousands of files from a list?

Tags: command-line, rsync, batch

So, I have a list of files in a text file. I believe it's about 100,000 files.

The files in said list are spread across many directories, have different sizes, filenames, extensions, ages, etc.

I am trying to find a way to move those files, and just those, to another drive.

Complicating factor: some of the files have the same name, but are not the same file. They can't just be moved into one folder with an overwriting or ignoring policy towards multiples.

Preferably, I would like them to retain their directory structure, but only have the files that I want inside the destination directory. (the destination drive isn't big enough to simply copy everything).

Below is an **example** of some lines in the text file that has the names of the source files:

```
media/dave/xdd/cruzer/F#(NTFS 1)/Raw Files/Portable Network Graphic file/3601-3900/FILE3776.PNG/Windows/winsxs/amd64_microsoft-windows-o..disc-style-memories_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_51190840a935f980/Title_mainImage-mask.png
media/dave/xdd/d1/other/hd1/Program Files/DVD Maker/Shared/DvdStyles/Memories/Title_content-background.png
```

---

I have tried to use

```
rsync -av `cat /sourcefile.txt` /media/destinationhdd
```

which complains that there are too many arguments.

Also

```
rsync -a --files-from=/sourcefile.txt / /media/destinationhdd
```

and

```
cat /sourcefile.txt | xargs -n 200 rsync -av % /media/destinationhdd
```

However, this just tries to copy my root directory to the destination.

---

How do I just copy the specific files that I want to?

Comment: would you care for a python script? and if so, would one directory be ok of the duplicates (names) would be renamed to: filename_1, filename_2 etc?

Comment: I would have suggested `--include-from`, but is that the same as `--files-from`, I don't even see that option in the man page.

Comment: Hi Jacob, Yeah, a python script would do me fine. 

I'd like to know why what I tried didn't work, though. The only thing I can thing of is the text file was unreadable by the command so it went for root instead? That doesn't sound likely, though...

Will try the answer below in the meantime and report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a little shell script for you:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line
do
    DIR=`dirname "$line"`
    mkdir -p "$2/$DIR"
    mv "$line" "$2/$DIR"
done < $1
```

Usage (assuming you saved the script as `script.sh` and made it executable with `chmod +x script.sh`):

```
./script.sh input.txt output_directory
```

It will move all files listed in `input.txt` to `output_directory`, using their original paths, for example, for an `input.txt` has the following list:

```
test.txt
dir1/test.txt
Another Test/something_else.txt
```

The files will be moved to:

```
output_directory/test.txt
output_directory/dir1/test.txt
output_directory/Another Test/something_else.txt
```

I did *some* testing before posting this answer, but please *make sure you try it on a smaller sample first* to confirm it's working as expected!

Comment: Thanks got me closer than ever, but... it seems to copy the directories without copying the files themselves. Error returned is 

        mv: cannot stat ‘/media/dave/xdd/.../waxing-crescent_partly-cloudy.png\r’

Thought at first it might be because of spaces in the filenames, but it happens for every file, even those without any spaces in the name. 

Then I noticed that it said /r at the end of every filename. Don't see how your script could have produced that, so could be a formatting issue with the list file, will have a look...

Comment: @NeMo Yeah, that's probably the carriage return character. Was the file created/edited in Windows? You should be able to fix it by `vi +':set ff=unix' +':wq' sourcefile.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, after I changed the lines to be unix lines it FINALLY worked.

edit: hmm, maybe not. Some of the lines seem to have retained \R. But some have been changed. Very confusing :/

Answer (score 1):

The following script first copies the directory *structure* from the source, then the *files* from your list into the corresponding folders. The line `if not line in ["", "\n"]` is to prevent errors in case the filelist contains empty lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import shutil

source = "/path/to/source"; target = "/path/to/target"; filelist = "/path/to/filelist.txt"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
    for dr in dirs:
        dr = root+"/"+dr
        destdir = dr.replace(source, target)
        if not os.path.exists(destdir):
            os.makedirs(destdir)

with open(filelist) as lines:
    src = lines.readlines()

for line in src:
    if not line in ["", "\n"]:
        shutil.copyfile(line.replace("\n", ""),
            line.replace("\n", "").replace(source, target))
```

**How to use**

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as move.py
- Add the appropriate paths in the head section
- Run it by:

  ```
  python /path/to/move.py
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with xargs fairly easily.

```
mkdir /newroot/
<filenames.txt xargs -I% bash -c 'mkdir -p /newroot/$(dirname "%" && cp "%" "/newroot/%"'
```

The tough bit is making sure the new directory structure exists. For that we use `dirname` to get the directory names, `mkdir -p` to build them and finally `cp` (or `mv`) to copy/move from one to the other. I've left it in copy mode so you can test.

I would suggest testing that `find /newroot/ -type f | wc -l` and `wc -l filenames.txt` both give you the same number afterwards.